# How to initialize a Vector within a struct for a node

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, nodes, kdtree

My issue is as follows:

I am making a KD tree with internals nodes as shown bellow:

```
struct internalNode {
    int DimForDisc; //Dimension For Discrimination
    int ValForDisc; //Value For Discrimination
    internalNode* leftChild, * rightChild;
    vector<vector<int>> leftLeaf;
    vector<vector<int>> rightLeaf;
};
```

As part of this process I need to initialize the vector<vector> when I make a new node. My current code for this is shown bellow: (due to restrictions I MUST use malloc/create my own constructor)

```
internalNode* makeInternalNode(int DimForDisc, int ValForDisc,
    internalNode* leftChild, internalNode* rightChild) {

    internalNode* PointerToNode = (internalNode*)malloc(sizeof(internalNode));
    PointerToNode->DimForDisc = DimForDisc;
    PointerToNode->ValForDisc = ValForDisc;
    PointerToNode->leftChild = leftChild;
    PointerToNode->rightChild = rightChild;
    PointerToNode->leftLeaf.clear();
    PointerToNode->rightLeaf.clear();
    return(PointerToNode);
}
```

At one point, after making the node, I try to set leftLeaf equal to another `vector<vector<int>>` by doing `Root->leftLeaf = AccumulatedData;` With the above implementation it results in a Segmentation fault, if I try to do something like:

```
    vector<vector<int>> leftLeaf;
    vector<vector<int>> rightLeaf;
    PointerToNode->leftLeaf = leftLeaf;
    PointerToNode->rightLeaf = rightLeaf;
```

it results in a SIGABRT and says free(): invalid size if I try to leave out initializing the vector entirely then I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555558b76 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::capacity (this=0xc3b00001716) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:996
996           { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage
```

I have tried everything I can think of but to no avail. I have confirmed that AccumulatedData is holding the correct information, so the issue really does appear to be when trying to copy it into the struct for InternalNode. Any help would be much appreciated, can add more info as necessary.

Comment: If you _must_ use `malloc` you _must_ also use _placement `new`_ to start the life of the objects you aim to store in the allocated memory in order for constructors to be called. You then also need to explicitly call the destructors when it's time to destroy the objects.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't fire construction semantics for those internal vectors (of vectors). Their content is *indeterminate* (fyi, even without the assignments just destruction is going to invoke UB). And when I say indeterminate I don't just mean the objects they supposedly hold; i mean the actual internals of the vectors themselves; the base pointer, the size data, etc. At a minimum you should use `new`; ideally you use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Though a dreadful idea, using malloc/free requires manual construction vial placement new, and direct destruction via explicit destructor call. I.e.

```
internalNode* makeInternalNode(int DimForDisc, int ValForDisc,
    internalNode* leftChild, internalNode* rightChild) {

    internalNode* PointerToNode = (internalNode*)malloc(sizeof(internalNode));
    new (PointerToNode) internalNode;

    PointerToNode->DimForDisc = DimForDisc;
    PointerToNode->ValForDisc = ValForDisc;
    PointerToNode->leftChild = leftChild;
    PointerToNode->rightChild = rightChild;
    // vectors are born clear, so I removed those superfluous executions.

    return(PointerToNode);
}
```

Later on at destruction time (wherever that is), you must do this:

```
PointerToNode->~internalNode();
free(PointerToNode);
```

That said, I discourage trying to mix C and C++ memory allocation and object management functions, and would suggest an official protest against using `new` properly, if not ideally using smart pointers in the first place.

Comment: Got my vote. To make it without casts: `void* storage = std::malloc(sizeof(internalNode)); internalNode* PointerToNode = new (storage) internalNode;`